# Trouble opening 'dplyr' in R dur to 'pillar' package issue

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use 'dplyr' in my code but when I call it, i get an error message -

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘pillar’ 1.4.6 is being loaded, but >= 1.5.1 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

I have tried updating 'pillar', 'tibble', 'dplyr' but it still gives the same error message after updating.
I am using R on windows 10.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the `pillar` package. Try removing and reinstalling the packages using the following code:

```
remove.packages("pillar")
remove.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("pillar")
install.packages("dplyr")
```

And load the packages again:

```
library(pillar)
library(dplyr)
```